# printing digits in reverse order using function in c

Tags: c

Hi I am pretty new to coding. So I was given this assignment by my teacher as mentioned in the title. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d in reverse order is ", n);
    printf("%d", reverse(n));
}

int reverse(int n) {
    int r;

    do {
        r = n % 10;
        printf("%d", r);
        n = n / 10;
    } while (n > 0);
}
```

Problem is, when I input a number, it gets printed in the reverse order but there is a `0` in the end. For example if I give `12`, it gives `210` as output. I can't figure out what the problem is, so any help is appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Please get a better guide book. [`void main` is wrong](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmainbooks.html).

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful there is more issues, the program is undefined because it declares value returned but doesn't return anything actually

Comment: In case your teachers told you to write `void main`, you should refer them to that page linked above.

Comment: I recommend that you also learn to use the debugger. It would have shown that the 2 and 1 come from within the reverse method and the final zero is from trying to print reverse's (undefined) return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior.

It is because you try to print return value of `reverse()` function, which is declared as `int`, but your function returns nothing.

Correct this and then print values inside your function `reverse()` only and optionally the return value of `reverse()` function separately.

```
int
reverse (int n)
{
    int r;

    do
    {
        r = n % 10;
        printf("%d", r);
        n = n / 10;
    } while(n > 0);
    return 0;
}

printf("%d in reverse order is ", n);
reverse(n);
```

Please note: this function will not print digits for negative integers in the way as you expect, because the result of remainder operator % is of the same sign as dividend, so in case of -12 [you will print](https://ideone.com/A1BLuo) -2.

Comment: Note: has a bit of trouble when `n <= -10`.  Likely OP does not care.

Comment: @chux OP apparently assumes positive integers

Answer (score 2):

You did not compile your program with warnings enabled, and that is why it has undefined behaviour. Always compile with warnings enabled and warnings set to errors:

```
% gcc test.c -Wall -Werror
test.c:3:6: error: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Werror=main]
 void main() {
      ^
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:18: error: implicit declaration of function ‘reverse’ 
     [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%d", reverse(n));
                  ^
test.c: In function ‘reverse’:
test.c:19:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Why you see `0` at the end is the *undefined* return value from `int reverse()` being printed out.

Since not returning a value from a function that is declared to return `int` is undefined behaviour, the output could as well have been `21-325987789234` or `21[2]    31941 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out`.

Your program needs 3 fixes:

1. `main` returns `int`
2. make `reverse` return `void` and declare it beforehand.
3. do not try to `printf` the return value of reverse.

Thus we get

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(int);
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d in reverse order is ", n);
    reverse(n);
    printf("\n");
}

void reverse (int n) {
    int r;
    do {
        r = n % 10;
        printf("%d", r);
        n = n / 10;
    } while(n > 0);
}
```

---

If you instead want to return the number that you get if you reverse digits of `n`, then you probably shouldn't print anything in `reverse`.